# Why vscode debugger require "program" property when I attach gdb to a running process?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, vscode-debugger

I'm using vscode for c++ development and want to make gdb attach to a certain process id. However, launch.json requires "program" (the path to binary). Putting dummy binary makes gdb attach to that process, and removing the property gives an error.

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Attach",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": 92796,
            "program": "...",  // ??
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description":  "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Presumably it uses the executable to load the symbols for you

Comment: Just a side/unrelated note: you can use a non-constant processId, so you can attach to any process: `"processId": "${command:pickProcess}"`

Comment: gdb doesn't need an executable to attach to a process, so this must be a CV quirk.